# Django template formatting leads to "ragged" html

Tags: django, templates

To my convenience I use some formatting in my templates (line breaks, spacing, etc.) For example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load tabs %}

{% block content %}
{% block navigation %}
<ul id="user_admin_tabs_list">
    <li><a href="{% url user_admin.views.profile %}" class=
    {% ifactivetab "user_admin_tabs" "profile" %}
        "user_admin_tabs_active_tab"
    {% else %}
        "user_admin_tabs_inactive_tab"
    {% endifactivetab %}>Профиль</a></li>

...
```

But this leads to "ragged" html output. Like this:

```
<ul id="user_admin_tabs_list"> 
    <li><a href="/accounts/profile/profile/" class=

        "user_admin_tabs_active_tab"
    >Профиль</a></li> 

    <li><a href="/accounts/profile/shops/" class=

        "user_admin_tabs_inactive_tab"
    >Магазины</a></li> 

    <li><a href="/accounts/profile/billing/" class=

        "user_admin_tabs_inactive_tab"
    >Биллинг</a></li> 

    <li><a href="/accounts/profile/settings/" class=

        "user_admin_tabs_inactive_tab"
    >Настройки</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Therefore readability of templates causes bad readability of output html.

What is the decision of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I wouldn't worry about the output of the template engine. You're going to be editing the templates, not the output, so for maintainability, it only really matters if the *template* HTML is well-structured. Sure, if someone uses "View Source" on your webpage, they'll see a mess of HTML, but that doesn't really matter that much.

That said, you could try using Django's [`spaceless` tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) to get prettier HTML output.

---

**Edit**

For this specific case, you could put the `ifactivetab` tags inline:

```
<li><a href="{% url user_admin.views.profile %}" class="{% if activetab "user_admin_tabs" "profile" %}user_admin_tabs_active_tab{% else %}user_admin_tabs_inactive_tab{% endifactivetab %}">Профиль</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I think you are right. Indeed - it's not too necessary to have a nice output page.

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about this in the past.

Your best bet IMO is to post process the output with something like `tidy`. It's written in C so it's pretty fast and won't incur much of a performance hit. It's an option in development but not something you want in production on a high traffic site.

You'll want to configure it to only indent code.

Off hand, I think it might try to clean up invalid markup which'll leave you scratching your head when you enable/disable it. Something to be aware of because the structure of your document might change as a result.

It's kind of nice if you're "viewing source" but you're probably better off just using firebug to examine your output anyway - if that's the motivation.